Как можно реализовать интерактивную схему узла автомобиля?
Существует множество картинок с узлами автомобилей. Мне необходимо из них сделать интерактивные схемы, подобные этой
https://avtoalfa.com/acat/cars/vaz/vaz-2101-3/1334088-3-1/8/10/
Подскажите, с помощью каких решений можно осуществить подобное.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map
